# Find camera's parameters of frame in OpenCV on Android

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, android-camera

I would like to know if there is any way to get the camera's parameters when you process video frame by frame using OpenCV on Android phones. For example, I would like to know the exposure time (not exposure compensation) of each frame or any other information (like ISO) about the active camera properties.

One obvious answer would be to set my camera parameters by myself and set the exposure lock but I am willing to find the exact exposure time (such as 1/2000 sec). Is there any way to do that on every new captured frame? I also know that you can add attributes to an jpeg photo with the 
`ExifInterface` but I do not know how to obtain those values.

One possible use case would be to not process the frames that are taken with a exposure time below a predefined value.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No there is not. This info does not come with the frame, and if you try to check the sensor registers while processing a frame, they may have already changed.

Comment: Any other suggestion on how to calculate or get the exposure time by having the exposure compensation locked?